# npm request - custom HTTP Headers for twitch data

Tags: api, npm, request, twitch

I have a assignment that getting the data from twitch API (Get Top Games). I used "request" module to connect to the twitch API. However, when I call the request, the terminal shows the status code is 401 because of the OAuth token is missing. I was wondering if there is an error in the headers of options object.

```
const request = require('request');

const options = {
  url: 'https://api.twitch.tv/helix/games/top',
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'myclientID'
  }
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
  console.log(response.statusCode)
  const info = JSON.parse(body);
  console.log(info)

}

request(options, callback);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [twitch API docs](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference#get-top-games), the `client-id` should be sent in separate `Client-ID` header, not under the `User-Agent`. Also, you need to pass the authorization token (App Access Token or User OAuth Token)

```sh
curl -H 'Client-ID: uo6dggojyb8d6soh92zknwmi5ej1q2' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer cfabdegwdoklmawdzdo98xt2fo512y' \
-X GET 'https://api.twitch.tv/helix/games/top'
```

In node.js `request` format, is should be something like this:

```js
var request = require('request');
var options = {
  'method': 'GET',
  'url': 'https://api.twitch.tv/helix/games/top',
  'headers': {
    'Client-ID': 'uo6dggojyb8d6soh92zknwmi5ej1q2',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer cfabdegwdoklmawdzdo98xt2fo512y'
  }
};
request(options, function (error, response) { 
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  console.log(response.body);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer. I am still not very clear for your answer. May I have you to explain it more? Thanks!

Comment: In your `headers` object, you're passing `headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'myclientID'
  }`. The API doc says that you need to pass the `'myclientID'` in the `'Client-ID'` key, as I passed above.

Comment: I still can't get the data and the terminal shows the same message
Error: Unauthorized, status: 401, OAuth token is missing.

Comment: Is there any precursor request to validata tokens?

Comment: I noticed that my url is different from yours "https://api.twitch.tv/helix/games/top". Does it cause the issue? And my API doc is "https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference#get-top-games"
Here is another question for -H and -X.  What are them for?

Comment: Updated my answer. Please refer for details about the API and authorization. The token and client-id specified in above example are dummy.

Comment: I changed the client id to my client id, but it still not works well. Is it something wrong with the Authorization?
'Authorization': 'Bearer cfabdegwdoklmawdzdo98xt2fo512y' or what should I fill after Bearer?

Comment: I can only show you the way: https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/authentication
  :)

Comment: Sorry, I got my client secret, but still send the invalid OAuth token.

Comment: https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/authentication/getting-tokens-oauth#oauth-client-credentials-flow

Comment: Thank you very much! I got the data from the API. You are the best teacher!

Comment: You're too kind :)